# Returning only 1 row from secondary table (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables (gallery and gallery_images):

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1=Active | 0=Inactive'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `gallery_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `orderNo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For displaying the results using PHP as a preview of the gallery, I want to show only the title of the gallery (from the gallery table) and the first image only (from the gallery_images table).

I have used this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.title AS maincategory, b.file_name 
FROM gallery a, gallery_images b 
WHERE a.id = b.gallery_id 
order by a.title
```

But it seems to return ALL the results. I only want the 1st image to return, not all of the images.

Comment: Which part of your query do you think should make it only return one image per title? `DISTINCT` applies to the entire select list, not a specific column.

Comment: You should use actual `join` syntax, not ancient comma joins with no relationship mapping `FROM gallery a join gallery_images b on a.id = b.gallery_id `